# AW Snap! Google chrome ran out of memory while trying to display web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest, out-of-memory

I am facing **" Aw snap! Google chrome ran out of memory while trying to display web page."**

Below is my simple application of calling an API in each second. After each call, the chrome memory allocation size for that tab increases continuously. But not reducing that memory. At the last that causes the page crash issue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div id="time">
    <h1>Time Sample Timer App</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="getTime()">Start Timer</button>
    </div>

    <script>

    function getTime() {

     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
          JSON.parse(this.responseText).time;
          setTimeout(getTime, 1000);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://date.jsontest.com", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me to find out the root cause of this.

I also posted a bug of my observation on [Aw Snap! Google chrome ran out of memory while trying to display web page.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711223&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)

But from Google side, no one is replying what is the actual issue with my application or google chrome itself.

Comment: it's because you allocate memory for each setTimeout but not clears them

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is the n number of setTimeout in the memory. It holds it and then you see the error message you got.  Solution is to ***use a named timeout*** variable and just ***clear it from memory before assigning a new one***.

```js
var time; // declare a time
function getTime() {
  if (time) {
    clearTimeout(time);
  } // clear if there is any prev setTimeout running
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText).time;
      time = setTimeout(getTime, 1000); // assign a new setTimeout
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://date.jsontest.com", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="time">
  <h1>Time Sample Timer App</h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="getTime()">Start Timer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it still increases the memory starts from 10000K and goes up to 12000K in 2 min.

Comment: Is the browser crashed? i am also on google chrome and it is using 45k+ and still it is smoothly working. So probably you need to  upgrade RAM.

Comment: Yes, I am not getting browser crash in this application. I am getting browser crash issue on my project. This is only to demonstrate to show why it's increasing memory. Because it keeps increasing memory and not reverting back.